# Enterprise OSGi vs. EJB

Tags: scalability, ejb, osgi, interop

i have an application server (JBoss) with some EJBs deployed. Now i must develop an OSGi application which i would like to reuse with my application server. I know that new application servers allows to deploy OSGi bundles in the application server itself.

These are my questions:
Could i simple deploy my OSGi bundles into the application server instead of EJBs?
Do OSGi services scale as well as EJB or should i better use EJB for performance-critical parts of the application(Is there are any "OSGi service thread pool" in application server)?
Will the OSGi service be the bottleneck for EJB-Based application if used together?

Thanks, Slava

Answer (score 1):

If you were using GlassFish, you could do use best both the worlds, as GlassFish can automatically make your EJBs that are part of your OSGi bundle available as OSGi services. See 
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ss141213/archive/2010/03/30/ejb-osgi-service-demo-eclipsecon

For more info, ask in glassfish forum at users@glassfish.java.net

Comment: doesn't answer or address original question.